# Why closure of a line segment in Zariski topology is entire C

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, zariski-topology

Following is from Smith's Algebraic Geometry book:

Let $S$ be a line segment in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $I \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ be the ideal of all polynomials that vanish on $S$. Then the closure of $S$ is the set of points where the polynomials in $I$ all vanish - i.e., $V (I)$. But nonzero polynomials vanish on finite sets of points and $S$ is infinite. It follows that $I = (0)$ i.e., the only polynomials that vanish on $S$ are identically zero. Since $V ((0)) = \mathbb{C}$, we get that the closure of $S$ is all of $\mathbb{C}$, as is the closure of any infinite set of points.

How "It follows that $I = (0)$" is correct? It can be an infinite number of polynomials in $I$? I know nonzero polynomials vanish on finite sets of points but how it is related to the conclusion that stated?

Comment: Zarisk**i**, not Zarisk**y**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal can indeed have infinitely many polynomials, but each must vanish on $S$, so $f\in I$ must satisfy $f(s)=0$, *for every $s\in S$*. In particular, each $f\in I$ must have infinitely many roots.

Comment: I can't upvote you for low reputation but I do in sprit